# AEM cloud, how do you install groovy console?

Tags: aem, groovy-console

There is a groovy console for AEM:

https://github.com/CID15/aem-groovy-console

However, I dont know how to install it for AEM cloud.

The instructions say to download it and run a local installer, which will install groovy console some how on the local machine.

However, this wont help the other users of our project, and wont work when the project is built on the cloud envs.

Presumably, we need to configure mvn to automatically download and install it, or possibly we have to put some sort of lib file somewhere in our ame project source?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's taken some effort to find a solution. Here we are installing the groovy console via the aem-easy-content-upgrade tool which uses it.

There are three files to edit:

pom.xml,  all/pom.xml and filter.xml

**pom.xml**

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>de.valtech.aecu</groupId>
    <artifactId>aecu.complete.cloud</artifactId>
    <type>zip</type>
    <version>LATEST</version>
  </dependency>
```

**all/pom.xml**

```
  <embedded>
    <groupId>de.valtech.aecu</groupId>
    <artifactId>aecu.complete.cloud</artifactId>
    <type>zip</type>
    <target>/apps/aemlab-vendor-packages/install</target>
  </embedded>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>de.valtech.aecu</groupId>
    <artifactId>aecu.complete.cloud</artifactId>
    <type>zip</type>
  </dependency>
```

**/all/src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml**

```
    <filter root="/apps/aemlab"/>
    <filter root="/apps/aemlab-vendor-packages" />
```

Then rebuild with your usual 'mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage' or similar.